# UITextFieldDelegate "shouldChangeTextInRange" not called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UITextField` and I want to use a regex for it. I want to use the

`- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text`

method from `UITextFieldDelegate`.

In my XIB-file the delegate is set to File's Owner. In the .h-file the protocoll is set 
`UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>`

`textFieldDidEndEditing` and `textFieldDidBeginEditing` are working correct.

`shouldChangeTextInRange` isn't called, but why?

best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because you are implementing delegate on `UITextView` and not `UITextField`. You should implement:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)iTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)iRange replacementString:(NSString *)iString
```

Comment: Could you please accept this answer for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 0):

You implement `UITextViewDelegate` method and try to delegate it `UITextField`. Try that;

Obj-C;

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)iTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)iRange replacementString:(NSString *)iString
```

Swift;

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```